# Does PyS60 produce sis files that are native?

Tags: python, symbian, s60, pys60

I am currently looking at developing a mobile apps for the S60 platform and is specifically looking at PyS60. It seems to suggest that the it can be compiled into native .sis files without the need for an embedded python interpreter. Reading through the documentations I could not find any statements where this is explicitly mentioned. While I am right now downloading the SDKs, Emulators, and the whole bunch of tool chains needed to test the development out on Linux, I thought I would ask here a bit while I am doing that.

Comment: Trying to get S60 SDK working on Linux is quite a pain. Still struggling with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is not officially supported for Series60 development yet. You will save yourself a lot of headache using Windows, weirdly enough.

As far as Python is oncerned, I think the developed application is packaged into a .sis file  but still requires the PyS60 interpreter to run once installed.

Answer (score 14):

Once you've written your code in python, you can convert this to a .sis file using ensymble.

http://code.google.com/p/ensymble/

This software allows you to make your .py file into a .sis file using the py2sis option - however, it won't be much use on any phone without python installed, so you may also need to use ensymble to merge your newly-created .sis with the .sis file for python, with a command like

./ensymble.py mergesis --verbose your-script-name.sis PythonForS60-1-4-5-3rdEd.sis  final-app-name.sis

the resulting final-app-name.sis file will install both your file and also python.